# Categories and subcategories with AJAX at Laravel project not working?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I can't select subcategroeis on change the categories select form

```
$.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"{{url('get-categorie-list')}}?cat_id="+cat_id,
           dataType:"json",
```

Comment: Do you have more info than a vague description and 4 lines of code( which is not even complete because we cannot see the end of your ajax definition)?

Comment: im new in stackoverfolw i'dont konw haw to dispaly all my code

Comment: Allright, if you use the code directly from the editor and paste it in so it aligns left, then select it and press ctrl+k. This will format your selection into `code`

Answer (score 0):

file wib.php

```
Route::get('get-categorie-list/{cat_id}','AnnonceController@getSubcatList');
```

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cat" class="col-md-3 control-label">Catégorie</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name='categorie_id' class="form-control" id='categorie' placeholder = 'Sélectionner votre categorie'>
        <option>Sélectionner votre categorie</option>
       @foreach($categories as $categorie)
       <option value="{{ $categorie->id }}"> {{ $categorie->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
       </select>

    </div>

  </div> <!-- form-group // -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cat" class="col-md-3 control-label">Sous Catégorie</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name='subcategorie_id' class="form-control" id="subcategorie">


       </select>

    </div>

  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
```

my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\State;
use App\Categorie;
use App\SubCategorie;
use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;
class AnnonceController extends Controller
{

public function getSubcatList(Request $request)
    {


            $subcategories =SubCategorie::where('categorie_id','=',$request->cat_id)->get();
        return response()->json($subcategories);

    }
```